# JQ: Selection with conditions in a nested hash

Tags: jq

How to get a city name specifying the name of a language with the additional condition of "spoken" or "perhaps"?

```
{
  "Paris": {
    "language": {
      "fr": "spoken",
      "en": "perhaps"
     }
   },
   "London": {
     "language": {
       "en": "spoken",
       "fr": "perhaps",
       "ru": "unused"
     }
   },
   "Moscow": {
     "language": {
       "ru": "spoken",
       "en": "perhaps",
       "fr": "unused"
     } 
   }
 }
```

E.g:

Input: en;
Output: Paris, London, Moscow

Input: fr;
Output: Paris, London

Input: ru;
Output: Moscow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert all entries to an object with key/value fields using `to_entries`, retain only those objects that do match your conditions (in the `.value`'s object `.language` the value of a field `$lang` provided as input variable using `--arg` equals `any` one of `"spoken"` or `"perhaps"`) and output the original entry's `.key`.

```
jq -r --arg lang "fr" '
  
  to_entries[]
  | select([.value.language[$lang] == ("spoken","perhaps")] | any)
  | .key

' input.json
```

Try it at [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/VdQWz1ZTxU)

Comment: Thanks that solved the issue!